# EC2 instance Linux, MYSQL log error:InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2

I have a working server running Ubuntu 64bit with apache2 on a t2 micro EC2 instance.
The problem is that MYSQL (version 5.5.38) has some bug...I tried everything, delete completely and restart without any database on it using this method [reinstall mysql](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265685/how-to-reinstall-mysql)
but when I run this command `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`I receive this message all the time:

```
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                 [ OK ]
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                 [ OK ]
* Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were not closed cleanly.
```

After some hours it become impossible enter inside the phpmyadmin, at login it shows me error #2002 wrong password. And than also if I restart the mysql I get this:

```
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                 [ OK ]
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                 [fail]
```

Inside `run/mysqld/` I don't have any **.pid** file.

The log file inside `/var/log/mysql` show me this:

```
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

I had also search for the process running typing `ps -Af | grep mysql` and than `kill -9 myid`, but after mysql starts automatically a new process.

I'm frustrated...also inside `var/log/apache2` I have a file called access.log huge, 71 Mb that repeating infinetely these lines:

```
89.248.168.46 - - [29/Sep/2014:02:21:15 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 790 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

is that also part of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [service](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/service.8.html) command to control the system services.

Comment: I'm a newbie of EC2, could you please tell me something more? Where is the service command? Thanks

Comment: from my management console everything is working...System Status Checks:
Instance Status Checks 

System reachability check passed 

Instance reachability check passed